# Parallel code bad scalability

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, scalability, task-parallel-library

Recently I've been analyzing how my parallel computations actually speed up on 16-core processor. And the general formula that I concluded - the more threads you have the less speed per core you get - is embarassing me. Here are the diagrams of my cpu load and processing speed:

[image: picture1]

So, you can see that  processor load increases, but speed increases much slower. I want to know why such an effect takes place and how to get the reason of unscalable behaviour.
I've made sure to use **Server GC mode**.
I've made sure that I'm parallelizing appropriate code as soon as code does nothing more than

- Loads data from RAM (server has 96 GB of RAM, swap file shouldn't be hit)
- Performs not complex calculations
- Stores data in RAM

I've **profiled** my application carefully and found no bottlenecks - looks like each operation becomes slower as thread number grows.

I'm stuck, what's wrong with my scenario?

I use .Net 4 Task Parallel Library.

Comment: Is it a real 16 core CPU or an 8-core with hyperthreading?

Comment: Indeed, but 32 cores gives 0% speed up, so I've ommited it

Comment: Are the threads preloaded with data or do they pull data as needed? If they pull data, how often, are there any wait time for pulling?

Comment: threads query for data - very often, but I'm not aware how to measure and what to measure

Comment: "threads query for data" - that sounds like a hotspot.

Comment: Could you spread this task across 16 machines rather than 16 cores on one box? Or do they need to run on the same host?

Comment: @cirrus The guys below told it looks like L1+L2 cache size is not enough. So I think in this case 16 machines wouldn't help

Comment: It could also be down to contention of shared resources on the host machine as others have suggested. A couple of things I would try are 1) buy an hour's time of an XL AWS box and run a test as the hardware will be different to your own, then try 16 small (not micro) separate instances each running a 16th of the data (if your algorithm allows for that). Finally, you could try 16 larger hosts and see how things improve. For 'embarrassingly parallel' algorithms 16 hosts is very likely to be quicker than 16 cores on the same box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to a linear scalability - in the context of where going from one to two cores doubles the throughput - is to use shared resources as little as possible. This means:

- don't use hyperthreading (because the two threads share the same core resource)
- tie every thread to a specific core (otherwise the OS will juggle the
  threads between cores)
- don't use more threads than there are cores (the OS will swap in and
  out)
- stay inside the core's own caches - nowadays the L1 & L2 caches
- don't venture into the L3 cache or RAM unless it is absolutely
  necessary
- minimize/economize on critical section/synchronization usage

If you've come this far you've probably profiled and hand-tuned your code too.

Thread pools are a compromise and not suited for uncompromising, high-performance applications. Total thread control is.

Don't worry about the OS scheduler. If your application is CPU-bound with long computations that mostly does local L1 & L2 memory accesses it's a better performance bet to tie each thread to its own core. Sure the OS will come in but compared to the work being performed by your threads the OS work is negligible.

Also I should say that my threading experience is mostly from Windows NT-engine machines.

__*_*__*_*_*EDIT****_*__*_*__*_***

Not all memory accesses have to do with data reads and writes (see comment above). An often overlooked memory access is that of fetching code to be executed. So my statement about staying inside the core's own caches implies making sure that ALL necessary data AND code reside in these caches. Remember also that even quite simple OO code may generate hidden calls to library routines. In this respect (the code generation department), OO and interpreted code is a lot less WYSIWYG than perhaps C (generally WYSIWYG) or, of course, assembly (totally WYSIWYG).

Comment: Also: Use per-thread heaps (by means of a multi-threaded allocator) if you do dynamic memory allocation

Comment: @KokaChernov I checked the question's tags and saw C# - which is not my cup of tea I'm afraid. But if you are interested here's a link (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/mem-alloc-1557798.html)

Comment: I mentioned earlier that only one thread should run on a hyper-threaded core. I've recently noticed that if the code is less tight and less optimal hyper-threading can do more with two instances of such code than with one instance of tight. So I'm guessing that the hyper-threading somehow manages to interleave the two code streams more efficiently: while waiting for a memory access to complete in one thread, a simple instruction might be executed in the other.

Comment: @trshiv: heaps are data and are covered by the statement "ALL necessary data AND code reside in these caches"

Answer (score 10):

You will always get this kind of curve, it's called [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).
The question is how soon it will level off.

You say you checked your code for bottlenecks, let's assume that's correct. Then there is still the memory bandwidth and other hardware factors.

Comment: what exact factors and how to measure them? if it can be improved by buying new hardware - I will.

Comment: You will have to measure/profile. For example, it's rare to have no dependency on the filesystem and/or Db.

Comment: Well, I would be happy to see at least 9x at 16 cores.

Comment: I think "you will always get this kind of curve" should be re-phrased "most applications will produce this kind of curve." Some applications actually scale linearly.

Comment: @OlofForshell - only when the parallel part approaches 100% very closely. That's actually covered by this law, as a (very rare) corner case. And in MiniMax problems there are even claims of super-linearity (speedup-factor > # processors)

Comment: @HenkHolterman The most confusing for me is the fact that I've parallelized exact piece of code that looks to be ideally appropriate, so alpha factor should be zero. So looks like I hit the memory capacity or some other factors.

Comment: @Koka Chernov: what you call "hit the memory capacity" is what I would generically call "saturate the memory bus" and implies that one or more of the memory buses controlling L1, L2, ... RAM is unable to deliver more memory accesses. In your case, if your code were ideal, you would spend close to 100% of your time in L1 & L2 and very little in L3 and RAM (or other shared resources). Given the significant alpha factor I'd venture to say you're spending more time in L3, RAM and perhaps other shared resources than you think you are.

Comment: This is of course a very general statement. One scenario which could lead to this has to do with code execution and not so much data accesses. It is possible is that your parallellized code does not fit in L1 and L2 but also requires a bit of L3. Then you'll run into swapping between L3 and higher caches. Since L3 becomes involved you'll get collisions with other cores.

Comment: @OlofForshell Very interesting thoughts. THe problem is that I don't see the way to measure all these aspects.

Comment: @KokaChernov - you never detailed the 'query for data' part but that still sounds like the first thing to look into.

Comment: One way is to profile with different numbers of threads to identify code/instructions which require much more cpu than would be expected after adding a thread. Then experiment with other code constructs and see if you can get a more linear progression.

Answer (score 3):

A general decrease in return with more threads could indicate some kind of bottle neck.

Are there ANY shared resources, like a collection or queue or something or are you using some external functions that might be dependent on some limited resource?

The sharp break at 8 threads is interesting and in my comment I asked if the CPU is a true 16 core or an 8 core with hyper threading, where each core appears as 2 cores to the OS.

If it is hyper threading, you either have so much work that the hyper threading cannot double the performance of the core, or the memory pipe to the core cannot handle twice the data through put.

Are the work performed by the threads even or are some threads doing more than others, that could also indicate resource starvation.

Since your added that threads query for data very often, that indicates a very large risk of waiting.

Is there any way to let the threads get more data each time? Like reading 10 items instead of one?

Comment: each thread does approx same amount of work, so it is balanced

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing memory intensive stuff, you could be hitting cache capacity.

You could maybe test this with mock algorithm which just processes same small bit if data over and over so it all should fit in cache.

If it indeed is cache, possible solutions could be making the threads work on same data somehow (like different parts of small data window), or just tweaking the algorithm to be more local (like in sorting, merge sort is generally slower than quick sort, but it is more cache friendly which still makes it better in some cases).

Answer (score 1):

Are your threads reading and writing to items close together in memory?  Then you're probably running into false sharing.  If thread 1 works with data[1] and thread2 works with data[2], then even though in an ideal world we know that two consecutive reads of data[2] by thread2 will always produce the same result, in the actual world, if thread1 updates data[1] sometime between those two reads, then the CPU will mark the cache as dirty and update it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc872851.aspx.  To solve it, make sure the data each thread is working with is adequately far away in memory from the data the other threads are working with.

That could give you a performance boost, but likely won't get you to 16x—there are lots of things going on under the hood and you'll just have to knock them out one-by-one.  And really it's not that your algorithm is running at 30% speed when multithreaded; it's more that your single-threaded algorithm is running at 300% speed, enabled by all sorts of CPU and caching awesomeness that running multithreaded has a harder time taking advantage of.  So there's nothing to be "embarrassed" about.  *But* with some diligence, you can *perhaps* get the multithreaded version working at nearly 300% speed as well.

Also, if you're counting hyperthreaded cores as real cores, well, they're not.  They only allow threads to swap really fast when one is blocked.  But they'll never let you run at double speed unless your threads are getting blocked half the time anyway, in which case that already means you have opportunity for speedup.

Comment: Thx for new knowledge, would be nice to have concrete implementation example

Comment: @KokaChernov I don't have one, just google "false sharing".  I know one technique is to allocate arrays size equal to your cache bank size even if you're only using one element.  Since arrays have to be contiguous, that guarantees each thread works on its own cache bank.  Though it obviously wastes a lot of memory.  But really a lot of that since it involves low-level memory management might be better to do in C++ and just P/Invoke it.